# How do I select the leaf elements of a nested list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, nested-lists

I need to select only the leaf link elements of a nested list
**Sample HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>folder
        <ul>
            <li>><a class="t-link" href="">folder</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="t-link" href="">leaf 1</a><li>
                    <li><a class="t-link" href="">leaf 2</a><li>
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So in this example I want to select the two leaf links but not the folder link
The folders can be nested infinitely deeply (but typically only 2-3 levels). I figure I need to look for li elements that don't contain ul elements but I can't see how you do that in jQuery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will select the leaf nodes that do not have other unordered lists as children:

```
$("li:not(:has(ul))")
```

Quick jsFiddle with color coded example: http://jsfiddle.net/rFuUc/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('ul').size() == 0)
    {
        alert($(this).find('a').text());        
    }
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/EXRBH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.t-link').parent().find(' ul .t-link')
```

should work.